# ¿Cómo incrementar el tamaño de margen del footer, TCPDF, symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony2, pdf

Hola cordial saludo a todos, tengo un inconveniente con TCPDF, ya que no encuentro la manera de **aumentar el tamaño de margen de la parte inferior**, como se detalla en la imagen el contenido sobre para al Footer.

Estoy utilizando TCPDF con Symfony 2.7
**Agradezco su atención.**
[image: Esto es lo que deseo hacer, aumentar este margen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con el método [`TCPDF::SetAutoPageBreak`](https://tcpdf.org/docs/source_docs/classTCPDF/#a4430365ea0b9015b4aefedad1ba77ea9):

> ```
> TCPDF::SetAutoPageBreak   (
>   $auto,
>   $margin = 0 
> )
> ```
>
> Enables or disables the automatic page breaking mode. When enabling, the second parameter is the distance from the bottom of the page that defines the triggering limit. By default, the mode is on and the margin is 2 cm.

Comment: Gracias compañero pero ya lo he intentado asi y no funciona solo me incrementa las margenes de arriba y la izquierda pero la de abajo no :(, TCPDF me esta dando muchos problemas, no se si talvez te haya sucedido este error: Undefined index: x error tcpdf.php at line 17321,

Comment: Perdona, me pillaste editando la respuesta. Mírala ahora, el método es la activación de la ruptura automática de página, en ella se define el margen inferior.

Comment: El error que dices está [aquí](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/master/tcpdf.php#L17321) y parece producirlo `$xoffset = ($this->x - $dom[$dom[$key]['parent']]['borderposition']['x']);` lo que significa que el índice `x` no existe en el índice `borderposition`, en alguna parte del código no se ha definido correctamente o debería comprobarse su existencia antes de operar con ese valor (siendo un bug de TCPDF).

Comment: si es ese mismo error y  sucede cuando utilizo `<div> TEXTO </div>` y este queda al final del documento, si resto texto y hago que quede mas arriba entonces el error no aparece, y **Gracias por la respuesta, por fin he logrado aumentar el margen inferior**